# recoger string de un Jtable y mostrarlo en un ComboBox

Tags: java, jtable, combobox, update, crud

Tengo un JTable que me muestra los motoristas insertados en mi base de datos.
Estos motoristas tienen una moto que también proviene de una tabla de mi base de datos. 
Para actualizar los datos de los motoristas, quiero que los datos de la JTable sean recogidos y mostrados en un formulario.
El nombre y la edad se muestran en un JTextField, por lo que no hay problema, pero la moto se tiene que mostrar en un ComboBox, y no sé como lograrlo.

```
//Aquí pulso el botón actualizar
if (e.getSource() == fm.boton_actualizar) {

        int fila;
        int filaSeleccionada;
        tablaListaMotoristas = fm.tablaMotoristas;
        fila = tablaListaMotoristas.getSelectedRow();
        DefaultTableModel tableModelo = (DefaultTableModel) tablaListaMotoristas.getModel();
        int id = (int) tablaListaMotoristas.getValueAt(fila, 0);
        String nombre = (String) tablaListaMotoristas.getValueAt(fila, 1);
        int edad = (int) tablaListaMotoristas.getValueAt(fila, 2);
        String motocicleta = (String) tablaListaMotoristas.getValueAt(fila, 3);
        String foto = (String) tablaListaMotoristas.getValueAt(fila, 4);

       //Creo un motorista para meter los parámetros recogidos en la JTable
        Motorista mp= new Motorista(id, nombre, edad, motocicleta, foto);

//abro una nueva ventana en la que se han recogido todos los datos del motorista.
        fma.setVisible(true);
        fma.setTitle("Actualizando Motorista");
        fma.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        fma.idActualizar.setVisible(false);

        JTextField campoId = fma.idActualizar;
        JTextField campoNombre = fma.ActualizarNombre;
        JTextField campoEdad = fma.ActualizarEdad;
        JComboBox comboMoto= fma.ActualizarMoto;
        JTextField campoFoto=fma.actualizarRutaFoto;

//pongo los datos del motorista en sus campos correspondientes
        campoId.setText(String.valueOf(id));
        campoNombre.setText(nombre);
        campoEdad.setText(String.valueOf(edad));
        comboMoto.setSelectedIndex(4); //este campo es el que no me funciona.
        campoFoto.setText(foto);


    }
```

[image: Aquí se puede ver como funciona el código:]

[image: Por si sirve de algo, estas son las tablas de mi base de datos:]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que llamar al metodo adecuado del JComboBox, que es el tipico addItem. un Saludo!

Aqui te aporto un Ejemplo.

```
public class EjemploCombo{

    private String obj;

    private JComboBox cmb;

public EjemploCombo(){

   cmb = new JComboBox();

   obj = "Aqui un ejemplo";

   cmb.addItem(obj);
```

}

}

Comment: Muchas gracias Jeysson. Lo he hecho como dices. Cargo el String de la fila en una variable y la añado al item.

Comment: Después, llamo al mismo método que me carga el comboBox en el formulario principal. El problema es que ahora me carga dos veces la misma moto.

Comment: Perdona, soy nuevo y no sé como responderte de otra forma que no sea con comentarios, así que he editado tu respuesta añadiendo mi posible solución, ya que necesitaba meter código e imágenes para que vieras claramente lo que me ocurre ahora.

Comment: no @JorgeGarcíaCano eso no es válido y es considerado vandalismo, si tienes una respuesta útil entonces publicala en donde dice tu respuesta, así que rechacé tu edición

Comment: @JorgeGarcíaCano Bro mira te puse un Ejemplo fue, no tienes que almacenar tu objeto en una variable tienes, que Agregarlo directamente, Ejemplo comboMoto.addItem("Tu objeto");

Answer (score 0):

sí Jeysson, lo entendí. Hice lo siguiente y ya funciona:

```
//cargo la moto en un string
String motocicletaActualizar = (String) tablaListaMotoristas.getValueAt(fila, 3);

//la inserto en el combo
comboMoto.addItem(motocicletaActualizar);

//Llamo a un método que me carga el resto de motos existentes en la base de datos.
seleccionarMotoActualizar();


//este es el método que carga todas las motos de la base de datos excepto la que recoge del Jtable (porque si no, la cargaría repetida).
private void seleccionarMotoActualizar() throws SQLException {

    String motocicletaActualizar = (String) tablaListaMotoristas.getValueAt(tablaListaMotoristas.getSelectedRow(), 3);
    JComboBox comboMotos = fma.ActualizarMoto;
    MotocicletaDao miMotoDao = new MotocicletaDao();
    ArrayList< Motocicleta> listaMotos = miMotoDao.findAll();
    for (int i = 0; i < listaMotos.size(); i++) {
        String moto=listaMotos.get(i).getId() + " - " + listaMotos.get(i).getMarca() + " " + listaMotos.get(i).getModelo() + " " + listaMotos.get(i).getCilindrada();
        if (!moto.equals(motocicletaActualizar)){
            comboMotos.addItem(listaMotos.get(i).getId() + " - " + listaMotos.get(i).getMarca() + " " + listaMotos.get(i).getModelo() + " " + listaMotos.get(i).getCilindrada());
        }
        }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchísimas gracias amigo!!!!!